# How to get the user initials programmatically in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm able to get this folder:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents
```

out of my code:

```
string myDocuments = 
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

I need to get the userinitials `(XXX)`, is there nice way of getting it, like `MyDocuments`?

If so I would prefer that clean way, instead of chooping the username out of my folder-path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may checkout the [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) property:

```
string username = Environment.UserName;
```

Comment: Thanks. I even tryed var user = Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile; before asking so not that far away :)

Answer (score 2):

use `Environment.UserName` to get the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Office application ask & store initials, but not windows
So, as other post, use Environment.UserName

Then, use this extension method to retrieve initials (it take first letter of each words)

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove any special character and return the first letters of all words
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">String to retrieve the initials from</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetInitials(this string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return str;

    var space = ' ';
    var previousWasSpace = true;
    var buffer = new char[str.Length];
    var index = 0;
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (c == space)
        {
            previousWasSpace = true;
        }
        else if (previousWasSpace && char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            previousWasSpace = false;
            buffer[index] = c;
            index++;
        }
    }

    return new string(buffer, 0, index);
}
```

This method is old and may be optimized

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to get the initials from username (splits by spaces or periods in this example):

```
foreach (string s in Environment.UserName.Split(" .".ToCharArray()))
    userInitials += s.Substring(0,1).ToUpper();
```